# Redirect 2 directories to a particular URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I already have this written in my .htaccess file.

## Redirects all traffic to my newsite.co.uk except for oldsite.net/dlg and oldsite.net/members

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dlg(/?$|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members(/?$|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*newsite.co.uk.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However my e-commerce pages at oldsite.net/dlg and oldsite.net/members are currently down.  So until these pages are back up,  is it possible to rewrite the above code, to remove the exception but make /dlg and/members divert to a particular page on my newsite.co.uk?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.co.uk// [R=301,L]
```

for further information
http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php